# Yen's K shortest Path giving incorrect results (Python)

Tags: algorithm, graph, networkx, python-3.7

I am trying to implement the Yen's K Shortest Path Algorihtm based on the pseudo-code from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yen%27s_algorithm. Here is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

edge_list = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 7], [1, 2], [1, 9], [2, 5], [2, 7], [2, 9], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 8], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], [5, 6], [5, 7], [5, 8], [6, 8], [7, 8]]
graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edges_from(edge_list)
nx.draw(graph, with_labels = True)
source_node = 8
destination_node = 9

def yen_ksp(graph, source, sink, K):
    A, B = [], []
    A.append(nx.shortest_path(graph, source=source, target=sink))
    for k in range(1, 1+K):
        for i in range(len(A[k - 1]) - 1):
            spurNode = A[k-1][i]
            rootPath = A[k-1][0:i+1]
            removed_edges, removed_nodes = [], []
            for p in A:
                if rootPath == p[0:i+1] and p[i:i+2] not in removed_edges:
                    removed_edges.append(p[i:i+2])

            for edge in removed_edges:
                graph.remove_edge(edge[0], edge[1])
            try:
                spurPath = nx.shortest_path(graph, source=spurNode, target=sink)
            except:
                for edge in removed_edges:
                    graph.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])
                continue

            totalPath = rootPath + spurPath[1:]
            B.append(totalPath)
            for edge in removed_edges:
                graph.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])

        if B == []:
# This handles the case of there being no spur paths, or no spur paths left.
# This could happen if the spur paths have already been exhausted (added to A), 
# or there are no spur paths at all - such as when both the source and sink vertices 
# lie along a "dead end".
           break
        B.sort()
        A.append(B[-1])
        B.pop(-1)
    return A

print(yen_ksp(graph.copy(), source_node, destination_node, 10))
```

This is supposed to be an undirected, unweighted graph generated from the above code.

[image: undirected, unweighted graph]

And this is the output of the code.

```
[[8, 5, 2, 9],
 [8, 7, 2, 9],
 [8, 7, 2, 1, 9],
 [8, 7, 2, 1, 2, 9],
 [8, 7, 2, 1, 2, 1, 9],
 [8, 7, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 9],
 [8, 7, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 9],
 [8, 7, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 9],
 [8, 7, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 9],
 [8, 7, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 9],
 [8, 7, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 9]]
```

Obviously there are shorter paths that the algorithm missed. And, the results contain paths that have loops. I want only the ones without.

Also, in other cases, the results were in the wrong order, some longer paths appear before other paths that are shorter. In the KSP problem, the order of results is obviously important because if I stop at some k, I want to be sure that there is no shorter path that I have missed.

I am open to other algorithms that can correctly and effectively solve this problem of KSP without loops on undirected-unweighted graphs.

Please help.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Top 10 shortest paths from source_node to destination_node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Networkx provides a function for generating a list of all simple paths in a graph from source to target, starting from shortest ones: [`shortest_simple_paths`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.shortest_simple_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.shortest_simple_paths). This procedure is based exactly on Yen's algorithm, as you can read in the documentation.

Using it is very simple:

```
paths = list(nx.shortest_simple_paths(graph, source_node, target_node))
```

If you want only the first K shortest paths you can make use of [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice
paths = list(islice(nx.shortest_simple_paths(graph, source_node, target_node), K))
```

Example:

```
from itertools import islice

K = 10
source_node = 8
target_node = 9

graph = nx.Graph()
edge_list = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 7], [1, 2], [1, 9], [2, 5], [2, 7],
             [2, 9], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 8], [4, 5], [4, 6],
             [4, 7], [4, 8], [5, 6], [5, 7], [5, 8], [6, 8], [7, 8]]
graph.add_edges_from(edge_list)

for path in islice(nx.shortest_simple_paths(graph, source_node, target_node), K):
    print(path)
```

Output:

```
[8, 5, 2, 9]
[8, 7, 2, 9]
[8, 5, 7, 2, 9]
[8, 5, 2, 1, 9]
[8, 3, 5, 2, 9]
[8, 7, 0, 1, 9]
[8, 7, 2, 1, 9]
[8, 4, 5, 2, 9]
[8, 7, 5, 2, 9]
[8, 7, 0, 2, 9]
```

If you want to understand how `shortest_simple_path` is implemented you can check out its [source code](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/algorithms/simple_paths.html#shortest_simple_paths): it's well written and very easy to understand!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, One question though. The command "nx.shortest_simple_paths(graph, source_node, target_node)" is contained within the islice command. So, is the shortest_simple_paths() calculating all the paths and islice is truncating it to the top K? Because that would be inefficient. If not, then what is it doing? and what is islice doing to the results of it?

Comment: I think I found the answer myself. shortest_simple_paths() yields a generator and islice iterates it for top K paths. So, it must not be inefficient as only k paths are found. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly! Using a list would be inefficient. Instead, a generator used with islice is exactly what you're looking for!

Comment: Thanks again. Any idea where my code could be wrong? My best guess is the try except block in the yen_ksp()